# How can i set a label text by a javascript function without knowing the label ID in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to set the text of a HTML label with various language translations. I know how to do it when i know the ID of the label, but i want to make a general Javascript function which does not require the id. In this order, I need some thing like this:

HTML:

```
<label> <script> translating_function("hello"); </script> </label>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
function translating_function(string) {
  //finding the translation (for example translated_text)
  returning translated_text
}
```

The return of the translating_function function should be set as the text of the label. 
Does any one have any idea how to do it. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: You have to have something to target, position, index, parent, child etc, or is this the only label in the document?

Comment: do you know the parent of the label object? then you can try to find it by parent/child relationship.

Comment: @adeneo as this function is used to translate javascript alert messages too, it can not have any target or name.

Comment: @JayLane if i want to use this function for translating the javascript alerts too, is it possible to use parent/child relationships?

Comment: yes you can but I'd need to see the rest of your DOM layout to assist

Comment: Or pick up something like handlebars/angular and not reinvent templating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var voc = [
            {
              "AR":"أهلا",
              "ES":"¡Hola",
              "EN":"hello"
            },
            {
              "AR":"مرحبا",
              "ES":"bienvenida",
              "EN":"welcome"
            },
            {
              "AR":"و",
              "ES":"y",
              "EN":"and"
            },
            {
              "AR":"في اللغة العربية",
              "ES":"a España",
              "EN":"to English"
            }
          ];


function translate(ele,lng){
 for(var i=0;i<voc.length;i++){
  for(var k in voc[i]){
   if(voc[i][k] == ele.innerText.trim()){
    ele.innerText = voc[i][lng];
    break;
   }
  }
 }
}
function translateTo(lng){
var trc = document.getElementsByClassName("translatable");
for(var i=0;i<trc.length;i++){
translate(trc[i],lng);
}
}
//add this function to any event button.click,select.change or on load
//translateTo("AR");
```

```html
<p>
<span class='translatable'>hello</span> 
<span class='translatable'>and</span> 
<span class='translatable'>welcome</span> 
<span class='translatable'>to English</span> :)
</p>
<select onchange='translateTo(this.value)'>
<option value='EN'>English</option>
<option value='AR'>Arabic</option>
<option value='ES'>Espain</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

[jsfriddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fzvL79ja/1/)

```
<script>
function translating_function(str) {
  return 'translating: ' + str;
}
</script>
<label> <script> document.write(translating_function("hello")); </script> </label>
```