# Multi language page with Javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, multilingual

Currently I am working on web app that will support several languages. Therefore I prepared table in my database with translations. However, I am not sure how to populate web app with translations. The easiest way, in my opinion, is to put reference to appropriate translation in each element of the page. This would work great in PHP I don't know how to make it work in js or JQuery.

What I would like to have is the reference to array in divs like this:

```
    <div> {translation_array['login']} </div>
```

So that the div would "take" value from translation_array, but I lack the knowledge to do it. Is it possible to make it work this way?

If not, I would appreciate advices on how to make multilanguage web in js.

thanks

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228835/best-practice-javascript-and-multilanguage)

Comment: Since you are saying that you don't want to use a server-side approach (which is probably the best approach), you would probably be best served by just having the various pages, pre-written in the various languages and based on a user selection redirect to a pre-made page.

Comment: Probably easiest to accomplish using a library like Vue.js or Angular, you could bind the elements to aspects of a model, which would be your set of strings for displaying that region. When the user changes the active language, you update the model and the library paints the new values into the view.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40176555/how-can-i-set-a-label-text-by-a-javascript-function-without-knowing-the-label-id/40177938#40177938

Comment: I feel you got everything you need. On language change just call the javascript function which will load values from prefetched data structure preferrably JSON array and assign it to elements. $("#longin").text(jsonelement); and so on. Assign ids to elements on page. And on page load fetch all information from server in JSON array object each node to represent language and sub elements for id and value for that element.

Comment: So following up on the earlier comment (this question is too broad and should be closed, btw), you could also homebrew a similar solution. Instead of `<div>{some placeholder}</div>` go with `<div data-translatable-string="click-here-to-log-in"></div>`. On page load or language change do something like this: `$('[data-translatable-string]').each(function(){ this.html( languages[selectedLanguage][this.data('translatableString')]); });` -- languages would be an object like this: `languages['en']['click-here-to-log-in'] = "click here to log in";` and so on.

Comment: Hello, thanks for many good advices! I think Mamdouh's approach suits me best, so I will try it. I will let you know how it worked for me!

Comment: @user1857756 can you kindly check my answer to see if that satisfies your request? Thank you

Answer (score 10):

Use on every piece of text you want to change according to the language a `span` HTML tag because you can embed inline on every piece of HTML (contrary to `div` or `p` which have a `display:block` by default). Then for each `span` use a `class` with a name starting with a certain pattern, for example:

`<span class="lang-text1"></span>`

Then using jQuery's function `.each` change every `span` tag that matches the pattern `lang` in its class name, according to the selected language.

I put also here a simple example for you to check.

```js
var LanguageList = {
  "EN" : "English",
  "ES" : "Español",
  "PT" : "Português"
};

//languages Objects
var WORDS_EN = {
  "text1" : "text One",
  "text2" : "text Two"
};

var WORDS_ES = {
  "text1" : "texto Un",
  "text2" : "texto Dos"
};

var WORDS_PT = {
  "text1" : "texto Um",
  "text2" : "texto Dois"
};


window.onload = initialize;

function initialize() {
  var $dropdown = $("#country_select");    
  $.each(LanguageList, function(key, value) {
    $dropdown.
      append($("<option/>").
      val(key).
      text(value));
    });
    
  loadsLanguage("EN");
}

function loadsLanguage(lang){
  /*fills all the span tags with class=lang pattern*/ 
  $('span[class^="lang"]').each(function(){
    var LangVar = (this.className).replace('lang-','');
    var Text = window["WORDS_"+lang][LangVar];
    $(this).text(Text);        
  });
}
```

```css
div{
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="country_select" onchange="loadsLanguage(this.value);">
</select>

<div>
  <span class="lang-text1"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="lang-text2"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="lang-text2"></span>/<span class="lang-text2"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is a very simple example using jquery and json:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        let arrLang = {
            en: {
                'home' : 'Home',
                'about' : 'About Us',
                'contact' : 'Contact US'
            },

            es: {
                'home' : 'casa',
                'about' : 'sobre nosotros',
                'contact' : 'Contáctenos'
            }
        }

    $(function() {
        let lang =localStorage.getItem('language');
        changeLanguage(lang);


     $('.translate').click(function(){
         lang = $(this).attr('id');
         localStorage.setItem('language', lang);
         changeLanguage(lang);
     });

    function changeLanguage(lang){
        $('.lang').each(function(index,element){
             $(this).text(arrLang[lang][$(this).attr('key')]);
         }); 
    }

    })

    </script>

</head>


<body>

        <button class="translate" id="en">English</button> 
        <button class="translate" id="es">Spanish</button>

        <ul>
            <li class="lang" key="home"> Home </li>
            <li class="lang" key="about"> About Us </li>
            <li class="lang" key="contact"> Contact Us </li>
        </ul>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem many times where the translation has to be handled with JavaScript. The best solution I came up with is to send translation object from the server to the front-end. I will give you an example

First create folder with translation files. Than create another file where you can handle the translation. It purpose is to generate a JavaScript object which will be send to the front-end. In my case it was a **PHP** server so I created a file named **translation.js.php**

**/languages/en.php**

```
<?php
$_GET['FILTER'] = [
    "hello_world" => "Hello World",
    "result" => "result",
    "all" => "all",
    "brand" => "brand"
];
```

**/languages/bg.php**

```
<?php
$_GET['FILTER'] = [
    "hello_world" => "Здравей Свят!",
    "result" => "ресултати",
    "all" => "всички",
    "brand" => "марки"
];
```

**/translation.js.php**

```
<?php
// define the posibile languages you can have
$languages = array('en', 'bg', 'fr', 'es');

//set the language from $_GET parameter or any other technique to set the lang
$client_lang = $_GET['lang']; //I am not sure if this parameter has to be escaped

//check if you have the requested language
if(in_array($client_lang, $languages) {
     require_once "languages/" . $client_lang . ".php";
} else { //if the client language is not in languages array, set the default language
     require_once "languages/en.php";
}

$translation = <<<EOT
var translate = {
    hello_world: "{$_GET['FILTER']['hello_world']}",
    results: "{$_GET['FILTER']['results']}",
    all: "{$_GET['FILTER']['all']}",
    brand: "{$_GET['FILTER']['brand']}"
}
EOT;


echo $translation;
```

Than in your header of footer include the **translation.js.php** file depending on your business logic. In my case I needed to translate only content which was dynamically create with JavaScript so I handled it the the **footer.php** file

```
...
<script><?php require_once "translation.js.php" ?></script>
<!-- then include your main js file which will assume that the translation object exists -->
<script src="<?php echo PATH_R ?>views/assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

And last you **main.js** file

```
console.log(translate)
// how lets set the heading using jQuery
$('h1#main_heading').html(translate.hello_world)
```