# Is there a way to split HTML document into two files, structure and content?

Tags: html, optimization, separation-of-concerns, design-principles

As far as I know, it is considered a good practice in program development to move the strings to the separate files. It allows translators and copyrighters to easily work with them, without needing to touch files with code, and it simplifies implementing different languages in a program. I know it's possible to do so in web development with templates and some website engine. But is there a way to do it keeping the site static, as you can do with CSS and Javascript?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46008865/199364) for a way to accomplish this, using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is a markup language--the ML in HTML. In order to be useful, it needs to be wrapped around the content it is marking up so, no, you cannot separate the two.