# How to let this JavaScript/jQuery script use HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to make my small website multilingual, and after testing many options, this script seems to be the best:
( https://jsfiddle.net/imihandstand/fh1rcy97/1/ . Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47612798/4024828 )

```
<script>
var LanguageList = {
  "EN" : "English",
  "ES" : "Español"
};

//languages Objects
var WORDS_EN = {
  "text1" : "text One",
  "text2" : "<b>text Two</b>"
};

var WORDS_ES = {
  "text1" : "texto Un",
  "text2" : "<b>texto Dos</b>"
};


window.onload = initialize;

function initialize() {
  var $dropdown = $("#country_select");    
  $.each(LanguageList, function(key, value) {
    $dropdown.
      append($("<option/>").
      val(key).
      text(value));
    });
    
  loadsLanguage("EN");
}

function loadsLanguage(lang){
  /*fills all the span tags with class=lang pattern*/ 
  $('span[class^="lang"]').each(function(){
    var LangVar = (this.className).replace('lang-','');
    var Text = window["WORDS_"+lang][LangVar];
    $(this).text(Text);        
  });
}
</script>

<select id="country_select" onchange="loadsLanguage(this.value);">
</select>

<div>
  <span class="lang-text1"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="lang-text2"></span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class="lang-text2"></span>/<span class="lang-text2"></span>
</div>
```

But I have one huge issue with it: **It does not care about HTML-tags I use in it** - but I would need that. So text in <**b**> should be shown as bold, etc.

How could I change this script to make it use the HTML-tags? I tried for 2-3 hours and I'm unable to solve it...

Thank you very much!

Comment: simply change `$(this).text(Text);` to `$(this).html(Text);`

Comment: Please, while doing copy-paste of code, at least go through it and understand how it works and what it does.

Comment: variable-variables, yikes.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone OMG, I can't believe how much time I wasted on this... Thank you soo much, really! :)

Comment: @helloworld I went through the code for 2-3 hours - but unfortunately I'm very new to jquery, so I didn't know there could be an "html" instead of "text" :/

Comment: @SuperStormer I'm sorry, but I don't understand what your comment means. You probably refer to the code to be too simple and not the best solution. This could be true, but other options (like that i18n or so) are too complicated for me at the moment